# $SESSIOn com durabilidade

Tags: php, mysql

Ola como posso complementar o código abaixo para funcionar da seguinte forma preciso que a seção seja destruída uma vez por dia o seja se o usuário criar a SESSION no dia 01/08/2015 caso ele acesse a mesma pagina com aquela SESSION no dia 02/08/2015 a diante ela seja destruída só mantendo a seção valida caso a data dela seja a mesma. 
Sendo que preciso manter  **$SESSION['nomeSecao']** e **$_SESSION['usuarioIp']**.

```
     <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['nomeSecao'] = $secaoNome;
    $_SESSION['usuarioIp'] = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 


    if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'], $_SESSION['usuarioIp'] ))
    {

// Da Insert + 1 na tabela secao coluna view

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Use cookies para isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do Gerep:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['data_acesso'])) {
    echo 'Você JÁ passou por aqui!';
} else {
    echo 'Você NUNCA passou por aqui.';
    setcookie('data_acesso', date('Y-m-d 00:00:00'), time() + 86400);
}
```